# Ext group as derived functor of Hom

Tags: derived-functors, derived-categories

I am familiar with the definition $\operatorname{Ext} _\mathcal{A}^k\left( {M,N} \right) = \left( {{R^k}{{\operatorname{Hom} }_\mathcal{A}}\left( {M, - } \right)} \right)\left( N \right)$, the derived functor of the left exact functor $\operatorname{Hom}(M,-)$. But I was wondering what is
$$
\left( {{R^k}{{\operatorname{Hom} }_\mathcal{A}}\left( {-, N } \right)} \right)\left( M \right)
$$
the derived functor of the left exact functor $\operatorname{Hom}(-,N)$. What's the relation between the two different derived functors?

Comment: they are isomorphic

Comment: Do you know any reference on this point?

Comment: I am fond of Rotman's homological algebra textbook. He refers to the two functors as Ext and ext, until he proves them isomorphic and then sticks to capital Ext notation. Let me take a peek in the book to refresh my memory, maybe I will submit an answer...

Comment: It's a large diagram chase that I don't think I will be able to repeat in sensible fashion, so I don't think I will submit this as an answer. But it's theorem 7.8 in Rotman's book.

Comment: Thank you, I will check the book

Comment: Here's an online source: http://therisingsea.org/notes/Ext.pdf check proposition 4

Comment: Maybe you have a new edition? In my edition (first), 7.8 is about Ext, Tor is chapter 8.

Comment: There's probably a nice high level way to understand this fact. I'm not sure, maybe something like "if $P_N$ is a cofibrant replacement for $N$ in the category $C$, and $I_M$ is a cofibrant replacement in $C^\text{op}$, then both $M\times P_N$ and $I_M\times N$ are cofibrant replacements in $C^\text{op}\times C$ for $M\times N$ and so either may be used to compute the derived hom-functor"